# Выделить картинку в picture_box

Tags: c#

Делаю скриншот экрана, помещаю это изображение в `picture_box`, который, в свою очередь, растягиваю на всю ширину/высоту экрана без рамки и без границы. Получается полномасштабный скриншот рабочего стола. 
Затем пытаюсь выделить прямоугольником все это изображение от координаты (0.0) до (1920.1080).
Но получается выделить только до (1919,1079). 
Фактически, я не могу мышку увести в координату (1920.1080), только в пределах (1919.1079)

Куда девается 1 пиксель? Как выделить до самого-самого края?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

N значений имеют индексы от 0 до N - 1 включительно. Поэтому самый дальний пиксель будет иметь координаты (Width - 1, Height - 1).

Comment: не тот вариант